# aparece error JSONException No value for

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Este es mi codigo

```
               String line;
               while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                   result.append(line);
               }
               JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
               JSONObject usuario = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("usuario");
               String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

               if(resultJSON == "1"){
                   id = id + usuario.getString("id");
                   nombre = nombre + usuario.getString("nombre");
                   ap = ap + usuario.getString("ap");
                   am = am + usuario.getString("am");
                   correo = correo+ usuario.getString("correo");
                   direccion = direccion + usuario.getString("direccion");
                   numero = numero + usuario.getString("numero");
                   dispositivo = dispositivo + usuario.getString("dispositivo");
                   contraseña = contraseña + usuario.getString("contrasena");

                   }
```

y este es el resultado JSON

```
{
    "estado": 1
} {
    "usuario": {
        "0": "hola",
        "id": "hola",
        "1": "Hector",
        "nombre": "Hector",
        "2": "asfaf",
        "ap": "asfaf",
        "3": "alala",
        "am": "alala",
        "4": "hola@gmail.com",
        "correo": "hola@gmail.com",
        "5": "23255532",
        "telefono": "23255532",
        "6": "infierno",
        "direccion": "infierno",
        "7": "holamundo",
        "contrasena": "holamundo",
        "8": "1",
        "dispositivo": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: He intentado validar tu Json en [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) y  resulta que no está bien formado. El error es: `Error: Parse error on line 3:
{ "estado": 1} { "usuario": {   ` Si lo ves formateado, cierras tu objeto después de `"estado": 1 }`y luego es como si abrieras otro Json.

Answer (score 0):

El error

> JSONException No value for

es provocado al no poder obtener el valor de un key dentro del .json, seguramente en este el punto:

```
String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");
```

El .json que agregas no es válido, me parece que debería ser:

```
{
    "estado": 1,
    "usuario": {
        "0": "hola",
        "id": "hola",
        "1": "Hector",
        "nombre": "Hector",
        "2": "asfaf",
        "ap": "asfaf",
        "3": "alala",
        "am": "alala",
        "4": "hola@gmail.com",
        "correo": "hola@gmail.com",
        "5": "23255532",
        "telefono": "23255532",
        "6": "infierno",
        "direccion": "infierno",
        "7": "holamundo",
        "contrasena": "holamundo",
        "8": "1",
        "dispositivo": "1"
    }
}
```

esto para que el código que presentas obtenga los datos correctamente.

```
               //Convierte respuesta a JSONObject.   
               JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
               //Obtiene valor JSONObject "usuario".
               JSONObject usuario = respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("usuario");
               //Obtiene valor de key estado en JSONObject.
               String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

               //if(resultJSON == "1"){ //incorrecta comparación de Strings.
               if(resultJSON.equals("1")){
                   id = id + usuario.getString("id");
                   nombre = nombre + usuario.getString("nombre");
                   ap = ap + usuario.getString("ap");
                   am = am + usuario.getString("am");
                   correo = correo+ usuario.getString("correo");
                   direccion = direccion + usuario.getString("direccion");
                   numero = numero + usuario.getString("numero");
                   dispositivo = dispositivo + usuario.getString("dispositivo");
                   contraseña = contraseña + usuario.getString("contrasena");

                   }
```

Comment: Adicional, la comparación de cadenas en Java debe ser por `equals`, no por `==`

Comment: muy cierto eso podría provocar no obtener los valores del objeto "usuario", gracias. Se agrega corrección a código.